# Proof of property of relatively hyperbolic groups on Wikipedia

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, geometric-group-theory, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

The Wikipedia page for "Relatively hyperbolic group" lists this as a property of relatively hyperbolic groups:

"If a group $G$ is relatively hyperbolic with respect to a hyperbolic group $H$, then $G$ itself is hyperbolic."

Wikipedia does not provide a proof or reference for this property. Can anybody help me prove it?

I found another equivalent definition for relatively hyperbolic groups in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404040v1.pdf (found in the Wikipedia page's references section). By this equivalent definition $G$ is relatively hyperbolic with respect to $H$ means that

(1) There exist finite sets $X,R$ such that $X\cup H$ generates $G$ and the kernel of the natural map $F(X)*H\to G$ is the normal closure of $R$ in $F:= F(X)*H$.

(2)  For a word $W \in  (X \cup H)^∗$ such that $W$ represents $1$ in G, there exists an expression $W =\prod_{i=1}^{k}f_{i}^{−1}R_{i}f_{i}$ with the equality in the group $F$, where $R_{i} ∈ R$ and $f_i ∈ F$ for any $i$. A function $f : \mathbb{N} → \mathbb{N}$ is a relative isoperimetric
function with respect to subgroup $H$ if for any $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and any word $W ∈ (X ∪H)^∗$ of length $||W|| ≤ n$ representing the identity
in the group $G$, one can write $W$ in the form of that expression with $k ≤ f(n)$. The second condition is that there exists a linear relative isoperimetric function with this definition.

It seems like it would be easier to prove the property by showing that $G$ being relatively hyperbolic with respect to a hyperbolic group $H$ implies that $G$ has a linear ordinary/non-relative isoperimetric function for $G$. $H$ being hyperbolic tells us that it is generated by some finite subset $Y$. Then $G$ being hyperbolic relative to $H$ implies that $X\cup Y$ is a finite generating set for $G$. I wanted to show that there is a finite group presentation for $G$ with generating set $X\cup Y$ that we can use to get a linear ordinary/non-relative isoperimetric function for $G$. I got stuck. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is particularly easy. It can be proved using the results in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2985) of Antolin and Ciobanu.

We aim to use Lemma 5.3 of that paper to prove that $G$ has a linear Dehn function. To do that you first have to choose a suitable (inverse closed) generating set $X$ for $G$, which involves adding additional generators from the parabolic subgroups $H$ to your initial generating set. That ensures that geodesic words over $X$ that lie in $H$ are written over the generators in $X \cap H$.

Now let $W$ be a word in the group generators representing the identity in $G$. Since are assuming that the parabolic subgroups are hyperbolic, by adjusting $W$ using a number of relations that is linear in the length of $W$, we may assume that all of the components of $W$ that lie in the parabolic subgroups $H$ are geodesic words over $X \cap H$.

Now, by Lemma 5.3 of the paper, there is a finite subset $\Phi$ of non-geodesic words over $X$ with certain properties. By adjusting $W$ again, using a number of relations linear in the length of $W$, we can assume that $W$ does not contain any word in $\Phi$ as a subword.

At this stage, Lemma 5.3 of the paper tells us that there are constants $\lambda$ and $c$ such that  the derived word $\widehat{W}$, which we get by replacing each component in $H$ by a single element of $H$, is a $(\lambda,c)$-quasigeodesic in the derived Cayley graph (which we get by regarding all elements of the parabolic subgroup as generators) without vertex backtracking.

Since $\widehat{W}$ represents the identity element, this implies that it has length at most $c$ in the derived Cayley graph. But now the bounded coset penetration property (which is a fundamental property of relatively hyperbolic groups, and is stated as Theorem 2.8 of the Antolin Ciobanu paper) implies that there is another constant $\varepsilon$ such that $W$ has no parabolic components of length greater that $\varepsilon$. So $|W| \le c\epsilon$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

The statement  was proved [here](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0040938305000297?token=436542A2B9D2EA3EB597AC3B04DBBB387A1BF7C38BF31E402BA1D83110E69D9F96450463B7D01AF5B6519C5B6A535CA8), Remark 8.30 (2).

Comment: Actually an earlier reference within that same paper ("Tree-graded spaces and asymptotic cones of groups" by Drutu and Sapir) is Corollary 1.14.

Comment: Indeed, Corollary 1.14 also implies the statement.